# Creating Muliple counts using different where clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

The Below Statement works perfectly. It counts all the values from region 37000 and has a computed column no. What I want to do is add several more counts where I can change the where clause for instance to 38000 or 39000. Can anyone help me out... Thanks

```
SELECT a.region, COUNT(*) AS [computedCol1]    
(
SELECT  DISTINCT table1.serial1, table1.serial2,
    CASE WHEN table2.serial1 IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS [computedCol1],
    CASE WHEN table3.serial2 IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS [computedCol2],
    CASE WHEN table3.serial2 IS NULL AND table2.serial1 IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS [computedCol3]

FROM    table1
        LEFT JOIN table2
            ON table2.serial1 = table1.serial1
        LEFT JOIN dbo.EPG
            table3.serial2 = table1.serial2
)a where region = '37000' and [computedCol1]= 'No'
    group by a.region
```

Comment: I think the query is missing a FROM clause before the first parentheses.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

`WHERE region in ('37000','38000','39000')`

as you are grouping by region, you would get three different rows for each region with its count.

Comment: Thank You. This worked perfectly. Is there any sql tutorial you'd recommend where I could learn the intermediate features. I'm not all that comfortable in it at the moment

Comment: i think you could start with http://www.w3schools.com/sql/ , simple tutorials and gives you the possibility to try queries online =)

Comment: [Will I be downvoted for giving a W3Schools link?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120025/will-i-be-downvoted-for-giving-a-w3schools-link)